# Avocado leaves drooping

Tags: leaves, watering, pruning, avocado, repotting

[image]

Why are my avocado’s leaves pointing down? I water it once a week and everytime i water it, the leaves raise up a little. Should I water it more often? I am afraid of rotting roots.
Should I transfer it to a bigger pot?
Also, should I cut off the top leaves so it can grow more branches?

[image]